# org-babel-tangle-file multiple files into a single output

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Is there a way to tangle an org file with `#+INCLUDE:` statements? Or other ways to tangle multiple org files into a single output?

Comment: Very fun questions! You may want to create a separate question for the `#+include:` statement because the include directive uses the export workflow rather than a tangled workflow.

Comment: Does [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/61278/tangle-org-file-containing-include-directives-and-multiple-tangle-targets/61423#61423) answer your question?