# Tangle Org file containing #+INCLUDE directives and multiple tangle targets

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

### Context

I'm using `org-babel-tangle` to generate my configuration from an Org file `config.org`. Recently, I did some clean-up by

1. dispatching `config.org` to multiple Org files `config/*.org`;
2. replace the content of `config.org` with multiple `#+INCLUDE: config/*.org` directives.

To illustrate a bit, the directory tree is as follows:

```
config/
|______ A.org
|______ B.org
|______ C.org
|
config.org
```

where

```
## config.org
#+INCLUDE: config/A.org
#+INCLUDE: config/B.org
#+INCLUDE: config/C.org
...
```

and

```
## [ABC].org
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle target1.el
;; elisp code
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle target2.el
;; elisp code
#+END_SRC
...
```

### Issue & attempt

However, I ran into the issue that `org-babel-tangle` doesn't handle `#+INCLUDE` directives. So, I follow the idea of [this post](https://dev.to/jfhbrook/multi-file-org-babel-tangles-with-include-directives-5522) which consists of

1. exporting `config.org` to an Org file `config-export.org` with `org-export-to-file`;
2. `org-babel-tangle` the exported Org file `config-export.org` to tangle targets.

This approach does replace the multiple `#+INCLUDE` directives of `config.org` by the content of `config/*.org`, but all tangle options are **erased**. Namely, the exported `config-export.org` looks like this (all emacs-lisp tangle target filename are lost):

```
## config-export.org
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
;; elisp code for target1.el
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
;; elisp code for target2.el
#+END_SRC
...
```

### Question

How to `org-babel-tangle` an Org file with `#+INCLUDE` directives as it is intended?

(*i.e.* (1) include all Org files (preserving `:tangle target.el`), then (2) `org-babel-tangle` the whole Org file.)

### Related question

A similar [question](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2010-09/msg00808.html) has been raised in the Org mode mailing-list.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to tangle to different/unique file names inside each of the included org files?

Comment: @Melioratus I would want to include Org files at first, then tangle each code block to potentially different files.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Very fun question! There are several ways to do what you’re asking using existing functionality without writing a lot of custom code so I’ll post a multi method answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to do this without changing the code (it might be possible with `org-babel-pre-tangle-hook` but it did not seem at all simple, so I didn't try that). But as soon as you accept code changes, it does not seem too bad.

The simplest possible way I could think of was to emulate in `org-babel-tangle` what `org-export-as` is doing WRT included files. A simple test (similar to what you describe above) succeeded easily (but see caveats at the end), so if you want to try replicating the change, I include the patch below.

The patch itself would look big, but that's only because I'm taking all of the code of `org-babel-tangle` and enclosing it in another layer, which changes the indentation and that's most of the change. Ignoring whitespace changes, the "real" change is much smaller: I got the patch below with `git diff -b` in order to ignore whitespace. You can then see that it is very small: we just enclose almost the whole body of `org-babel-tangle` in `(org-export-with-buffer-copy ...)`, so that we can do transformations to the text in a temp buffer and not disturb the original and then add one more transformation to process the `#+INCLUDE:` directives, before the resulting buffer is then tangled:

```el
diff --git a/lisp/ob-tangle.el b/lisp/ob-tangle.el
index b74b3fa0c..5e6eebf63 100644
--- a/lisp/ob-tangle.el
+++ b/lisp/ob-tangle.el
@@ -206,6 +206,9 @@ export file for all source blocks.  Optional argument LANG-RE can
 be used to limit the exported source code blocks by languages
 matching a regular expression."
   (interactive "P")
+  (org-export-with-buffer-copy
+   (org-export-expand-include-keyword)
+
    (run-hooks 'org-babel-pre-tangle-hook)
    ;; Possibly Restrict the buffer to the current code block
    (save-restriction
@@ -306,7 +309,7 @@ matching a regular expression."
     (mapc (lambda (pair)
         (when (cdr pair) (set-file-modes (car pair) (cdr pair))))
           path-collector)
-   (mapcar #'car path-collector)))))
+    (mapcar #'car path-collector))))))
 
 (defun org-babel-tangle-clean ()
   "Remove comments inserted by `org-babel-tangle'.
```

That produces the expected results WRT the tangled files I think, but you should check to make sure that it does the right thing in your case: my tests are toy tests so they might miss tricky situations that might arise in your "real world" tests.

There is one problem which I don't understand yet: the `config.org` buffer itself is changed in my tests, despite the `org-export-with-copy-buffer`, so at the end of the tangle I have to undo the change with `C-x u` and save it. That's probably because I don't understand what `org-export-with-copy-buffer` is really doing, but I have not checked that code yet.

OTOH, if that is resolved and the tests all pass, we can propose this as an enhancement to the Org mode mailing list and put that problem (from 2010!) behind us.

EDIT: I don't see any problem with `org-babel-tangle-file` - it calls `org-babel-tangle` underneath, so in theory it should do the (almost) right thing and testing it with a simple example works fine for me. Maybe you can post a (small) example that gives you problems by editing your question?

I'm also testing with the following workaround to get around the issue of `config.org` getting changed:

```el
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(copy-file "./config.org.orig" "./config.org")
(org-babel-tangle-file "./config.org")
(delete-file "./config.org")
#+end_src
```

Ugly, but it seems to work (except that I have to answer the "changed on disk" question).

Comment: Thanks again for your answer! It's almost perfect, here are my observations: (1) We need to add `(require 'ox)` somewhere. I added it under the `interactive` call. (If it is put at the very beginning, it would cause circular load). (2) It works interactively on `config.org` modulo the issue of expanding `#+INCLUDE` on the original buffer. Programmatically, I call `org-babel-tangle-file "config.org"` and `#+INCLUDE` directives are not expanded. Maybe it's a buffer issue ? I'm not sure.

Comment: It's quite odd that this 2010 question has not been followed up as it is a very natural thing one would want to do. Maybe at the time, a solution would require more than two lines.

Comment: Thanks! I'll see what I can do about `org-babel-tangle-file` as well as about the unwanted expansion in the buffer. If this does make it into Org mode, the `require` will be at the top level of `ob-tangle.el`, rather than inside the function. But it may be that `org-export-with-copy-buffer` is not quite right and something else will need to take its place.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit odd but both of the people responsible for babel and tangle moved on to other projects and the export mechanism has since been rewritten from scratch: neither of the `org-export-...` functions above existed in the original implementation.

Comment: Unfortunately `org-export-expand-include-keyword` is not found in my Emacs 26.3. What function should I use?

Comment: I would highly recommend upgrading: the function was introduced in 2012 and git says it should be available in Org 7.9. The current version is 9.6. If your version of Org mode (check with `M-x org-version) is that old, you *really* want to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

### Method 1

Manual method using default org-mode keybindings

#### Setup

1. Add `Org` to `Org Babel Load Languages` configuration and then apply and save new configuration.
2. Add `#+EXPORT_FILE_NAME:` keyword near top of `config.org`.

   e.g.

   ```
   #+EXPORT_FILE_NAME: temp.org
   ```
3. Add `#+PROPERTY: header-args:org :results drawer replace` keyword near top of `config.org`.

   e.g.

   ```
   #+PROPERTY: header-args:org :results drawer replace
   ```
4. Update `#+INCLUDE:` to include the `src org` syntax.

   e.g.

   ```
   #+INCLUDE: config/A.org src org
   #+INCLUDE: config/B.org src org
   #+INCLUDE: config/C.org src org
   ```
5. Add `:eval never` header to each of `SRC` blocks that will be tangled inside the included `config/*.org` files.

   e.g.

   ```
   #+BEGIN_SRC elisp :tangle tangle1.el :eval never 
     ;; Code goes here
   #+END_SRC
   ```

#### Manual Execution Steps

1. Open `config.org` in emacs.

   The `config.org` file should look similar to the example below:

   ```
   #+EXPORT_FILE_NAME: temp.org
   #+PROPERTY: header-args:org :results drawer replace 

   #+INCLUDE: config/A.org src org
   #+INCLUDE: config/B.org src org
   #+INCLUDE: config/C.org src org
   ```
2. Export `config.org` using `C-c` `C-e` `O` `v` key chord. This will create a new `temp.org` file and open in emacs.

   The `temp.org` file should look similar to the example below:

   ```
   #+export_file_name: temp.org
   #+property: header-args:org :results drawer replace

   #+begin_src org
     ,#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :tangle tangle1.el :eval never 
       ;; Code goes here
     ,#+END_SRC
   #+end_src
   #+begin_src org
     ,#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :tangle tangle2.el :eval never 
       ;; Code goes here
     ,#+END_SRC
   #+end_src
   #+begin_src org
     ,#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :tangle tangle3.el :eval never 
       ;; Code goes here
     ,#+END_SRC
   #+end_src
   ```
3. Execute all the blocks in the `temp.org` using `C-c` `C-v` `C-b` key chord.

   The `temp.org` file should look similar to the example below:

   ```
   #+export_file_name: temp.org
   #+property: header-args:org :results drawer replace

   #+begin_src org
     ,#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :tangle tangle1.el :eval never 
       ;; Code goes here
     ,#+END_SRC
   #+end_src

   #+RESULTS:
   :results:
   #+BEGIN_SRC elisp :tangle tangle1.el :eval never 
     ;; Code goes here
   #+END_SRC
   :end:

   #+begin_src org
     ,#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :tangle tangle2.el :eval never 
       ;; Code goes here
     ,#+END_SRC
   #+end_src

   #+RESULTS:
   :results:
   #+BEGIN_SRC elisp :tangle tangle2.el :eval never 
     ;; Code goes here
   #+END_SRC
   :end:

   #+begin_src org
     ,#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :tangle tangle3.el :eval never 
       ;; Code goes here
     ,#+END_SRC
   #+end_src

   #+RESULTS:
   :results:
   #+BEGIN_SRC elisp :tangle tangle3.el :eval never 
     ;; Code goes here
   #+END_SRC
   :end:
   ```
4. Execute the tangle in the `temp.org` using `C-c` `C-v` `C-t` key chord. This will tangle the imported `SRC` blocks from the `config/*.org` files.

   This will create the tangled files similar to the files listing below:

   ```
   config.org
   tangle1.el
   tangle2.el
   tangle3.el
   temp.org

   ./config:
   A.org
   B.org
   C.org
   ```

---

> **This answer was tested using:**
> **emacs version:** GNU Emacs 27.1
> **org-mode version:** 9.3.7

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it still helps and if it is exactly what you need... I am using something like within spacemacs:

```lisp
  ;;-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (message "--- START : filemanage ----")
  (let ((srcuf (concat dotspacemacs-directory "user_filemanage.org"))
        (uf (concat dotspacemacs-directory "user-filemanage.el"))
        )
    (when (file-newer-than-file-p srcuf uf)

      (message "--- File is adjusted : filemanage ----")
      (call-process
       (concat invocation-directory invocation-name)
       nil nil t
       "-q" "--batch" "--eval" "(require 'ob-tangle)"
       "--eval" (format "(org-babel-tangle-file \"%s\")" srcuf)))
    )

  (message "--- DONE : filemanage ----")
  ;;-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (message "--- START : helm ----")
  (let ((srcuh (concat dotspacemacs-directory "user_helm.org"))
        (uh (concat dotspacemacs-directory "user-helm.el"))
        )
    (when (file-newer-than-file-p srcuh uh)

      (message "--- File is adjusted : helm ----")
      (call-process
       (concat invocation-directory invocation-name)
       nil nil t
       "-q" "--batch" "--eval" "(require 'ob-tangle)"
       "--eval" (format "(org-babel-tangle-file \"%s\")" srcuh)))
    )
```

And for loading within the config section

```lisp
  (let ((uf (concat dotspacemacs-directory "user-filemanage.el")))
    (load-file uf))
  (let ((uh (concat dotspacemacs-directory "user-helm.el")))
    (load-file uh))
```

and in `user_filemanage.el` I have something like

```
*** dired-open
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle user-filemanage.el
;; dired open.............................................................................
(require 'dired-open)  
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: Thanks, I see the idea here, and it can be generalized by looping over `.org` files under a directory. I didn't try thoroughly other answers yet due to lack of time at the moment of asking this question. So my configuration is still in a messy state... Will check them asap.